# UPDATE query dependent upon previous row's value

Tags: mysql, sql, moving-average

I am trying to calculate a 200-row exponential moving average (EMA) using an SQL query with MySQL. Each row is dependent on the value of the previous row. The formula is:

```
EMA = ((price - EMA(previous_average)) * (2 / (200 + 1))) + EMA(previous_average)
```

My table initallly looks like

```
id       price      average
---------------------------
1        29.05      29.05000000
2        29.04       0.00000000
3        29.06       0.00000000
4        29.05       0.00000000
```

(I manually set the first row's "average" to "price" so the query below has an initial value)

Running this query

```
UPDATE
  quotes
INNER JOIN
  quotes AS quotes_previous ON quotes_previous.id = table.id - 1
SET
  table.average = ((quotes.price - quotes_previous.average) * (2 / (200 + 1)) + quotes_previous.average)
where
  quotes.id > 1
```

my table then looks like

```
id       price      average
---------------------------
1        29.05      29.05000000
2        29.04      29.04990050
3        29.06       1.13937059
3        29.05       1.13927205
```

As you can see, the average is clearly incorrect for all but the first two rows.

I believe the problem is that the query needs to update the rows in order by id. But when I add "ORDER BY id" to the query, I get "Error 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY." I believe I cannot use ORDER BY with a JOIN in an UPDATE query.

So, how can I run an UPDATE query that is dependent upon the previous row's value?

Comment: Do you mean on the previous rows *updated* value or the value before the update?

Comment: If you want to use the previous row's updated value, the answer is "Nope, you can't do that."  An update is executed as a single transaction.  Any given value doesn't go into the table until all the values have gone into the table.  You need to do this using a cursor -- or to find another way to formulate the arithmetic.

Comment: @Gordon That is what I was afraid of. Okay, time to write a stored procedure...unless someone has a simpler solution?

Comment: I mean, I want to use the previous row's updated value when I update the current row.

Comment: i think you should change the average to price when average is zero.

Comment: @ChadJohnson . . . If you are considering changing databases, SQL Server, Oracle, and Postgres all have language features that can support this operation (basically recursive CTEs).

Comment: Have you tried calculating the averages in a subselect with ORDER BY with the help of variables, then joining the results back to the original table to update the target column?

Comment: @Andriy Have not. I usually don't use variables in queries, but I may give this a shot. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @adreal Can you explain what you mean a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```sql
UPDATE quotes q INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id,
       price,
       ((price - @prev) * (2 / (200 + 1))) + @prev average,
       @prev = ((price - @prev) * (2 / (200 + 1))) + @prev
  FROM quotes, (SELECT @prev := (SELECT price FROM quotes ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) i) n
 ORDER BY id) t ON q.id=t.id
   SET q.average = t.average
```

Output

```
+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | price | average     |
+------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | 29.05 | 29.05000000 |
|    2 | 29.04 | 29.04990050 |
|    3 | 29.06 | 29.05009950 |
|    4 | 29.05 | 29.05000000 |
+------+-------+-------------+
```

It meant to be safe to re-run since it takes first average from the price column of the row with the lowest id.

Comment: Damn. I saw this too late. I ended up using a stored procedure. Thank you for this, though.